# Why when I convert the same C++ string in MD5 hash I obtain every time a different output?

Tags: c++, md5

I have a string converted to an MD5 hash using a python script with the following command:

```py
admininfo['password'] = hashlib.md5(admininfo['password'].encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
```

This value is now stored in an online database.

Now I'm creating a C++ script to do a login on this database. During the login, I ask for the password and I convert it to an MD5 hash to compare it with the value from the online database.

But giving the same string, I obtain a different MD5 hash value every time.

How can I fix it?

```cpp
cin >> Admin_pwd;
cout << endl;

unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
const char* string = Admin_pwd.c_str();

MD5((unsigned char*)&string, strlen(string), (unsigned char*)&digest);    

char mdString[33];

for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

printf("md5 digest: %s\n", mdString);
```

First try:

`md5 digest: dcbb3e6add7fb94b98c56d7f70b7c46e`

Second try:

`md5 digest: 2870f4de491ad17d53d6d6e9dae19ca9`

Third try:

`md5 digest: 84656428baf461093e9fca2c8b05a296`

Comment: Please don't use C-style casts in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(unsigned char*)&string
```

You're hashing the pointer itself (and unspecified data after it), not the string that it points to.

And it changes on every execution (maybe).

You meant just `(unsigned char*)string`.

Answer (score 2):

Make it `MD5((unsigned char*)string, ...)`; drop the ampersand. You are not passing the character data to `MD5` - you are passing the value of the `string` pointer itself (namely, the address of the first character of the password), plus whatever garbage happens to be on the stack after it.